# Automatic \clearpage when picture goes on the next page

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a small problem. I'm writing my PhD thesis (that's not the problem) and I want my images to be where I want them to be. I manage to do that using

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\end{figure}
```

but often the pictures goes on the next page. I really don't mind but the text is then spread out all over the page. I can fix the problem localy by adding `\clearpage` but I'm feeling using microsoft Word when I do so and of course when I add some text I have to change the position of the clearpage commands.

Do you know how to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: using `H` is a request to get unpleasant white space in your document it is an explicit instruction to disable the float mechanism which is there to avoid white spaces. Perhaps you want `\raggedbottom` rather that `\flushbottom` so the space comes at the end of the page, but not using `H` is usually better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. '\raggedbottom' works very well. Do you have other solution than using H? To me, having the images where you want in a document is a minimum, no?

Comment: In traditional printing you would not get a choice: the whole reason for the convention of tables and figures to be separate captioned items is to allow the (human) typesetter to fit them in to a place that works with the page breaking. LaTeX is only a program not a person, so if you choose to argue with it you can always win, but choosing not to argue could be a possibility to consider,

Comment: With the `needspace` package, you can request a vertain amount of vertical space in advance.  If not available, it will clear the page.  For example, try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,needspace}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\needspace{1.5in}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{1in}{1in}
\caption{This is my caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}`

Comment: you could "abandon" the `figure` environment, and instead use a separate package, like `captionof` to set the captions.  it might be necessary to pack the graphic and the caption together in a `minipage` if they would otherwise be separated by a page break.  plus `\raggedbottom` as mentioned by david carlisle.

Comment: Always "where you want" without wasting space is simply impossible, whatever you do. Best approach is "here if possible, less harmful place otherwise". This is  possible with wise control of options and floats rules. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) about float algorithm parameters. However, IMHO figures between text disrupt the lecture more than using top/bottom/page positions, so use [H] sparingly, only if you want stop the lecture at this point even at the cost of worse page layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the floating environment and use the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

and then

```
some text some text some text some text 
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{your-figure-here}
\caption{caption goes here}
\end{minipage}
other text other text other text other text
```

Anyway, I second the comment of David Carlisle, and strongly recommend to use floats and let LaTeX do the page composition (possibly using only the `[tb]` placing options).

Comment: This is a well-known equivalent alternative to using a (non-) floating object with the `H`specifier; it doesn’t solve the spacing issue, though.